# YARD attr_writer when manually created the reader

Tags: ruby, yard

I've created two attr_writer in a class, let's call them `foo` and `bar`.

```
# @attr_writer [String] foo Description of a writeonly attribute
class Baz
  attr_writer :foo, :bar

  # @return ....
  def foo ; end
  def bar ; end
end
```

YARD will not render the `foo` writer docs. I think that's because I manually are creating the readers.

Is there a way to go around this?

NOTE: I've also tried `@!attribute` but with the same result.